# Magento Soap api product custom option list not getting all options

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, soap, magento-1.9

I have installed mageworks advanced custom option extension in magento.

I am trying to fetch product custom option using soap api v2

I am able to get only following details

1. Title
2. Sku
3. sort_order
4. Price

And I required following details

1. Description
2. Qty

I am using following snippet

```
 $proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
 $sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
 $result = $proxy->catalogProductCustomOptionList($sessionId, '1');
 var_dump($result);
```

[image]

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this $result = $proxy->catalogProductCustomOptionInfo($sessionId, '1');